# HTML CSS clicked property

Tags: html, css

Is there a way of maintaining a button propterty after it is clicked. There are hoover and active properties but is there a "clicked" property? Check the link below:

http://bricbracs.com/hh/

You can click the various buttons which perform a function. Is there a CSS property to show which button is currently clicked?

Here is the CSS

```
.yearsx {
 font-size: 28px;
 letter-spacing: 1;
  }

.yearsx a {
 color: #888;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.yearsx a:hover {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: underline;
  }
 .yearsx a:active {
  color: #B51E1E;
  text-decoration: none;
  }

.monthsx {
 font-size: 28px;
 font-variant: small-caps;
 letter-spacing: 1;
 }

.monthsx a {
 color: #B593CD;
 text-decoration: none;
 }
.monthsx a:hover {
 color: #B52062;
 text-decoration: underline;
 }
.monthsx a:active {
color: #B5DE1C;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Here's the HTML

```
<div id="months"  class="monthsx">
<a href="javascript:void(0);"
 onmouseover=update_1()
 onclick="dostuff()"/ >
 March</a>

 <a href="javascript:void(0);"
 onmouseover=update_2()
 onclick="dostuff()"/ >
 April</a>

 <a href="javascript:void(0);"
   onmouseover=update_3()
   onclick="dostuff()"/ >
   May</a>
 </div>


<div id="years"  class="yearsx">
 <a href="javascript:void(0);"
  onmouseover=update_11()
   onclick="dostuff()"/ >
 1990</a>

<a href="javascript:void(0);"
  onmouseover=update_12()
  onclick="dostuff()"/ >
  1991</a>

<a href="javascript:void(0);"
 onmouseover=update_13()
  onclick="dostuff()"/ >
  1992</a>

</div>
```

Comment: Its called **visited:**

Comment: agree, visited: is as close as you'll get. And it works across page loads

Comment: Hey, it's not `visited:`! It is `:visited`. As in `a:visited { color: red;}` It is compiled based on your browser history. So once you visit a link, it will show up red (on the page where the CSS applies) until you clear your browsing history.

Comment: I don't see how's an anchor element a button

Comment: @Ankit Give `<a href="#" onclick="void(0)" class="btn btn-default">I am a button!</a>` a go in Twitter Bootstrap. And keep eyes open this time.

Comment: If you're here to troll and correct the slightest misuse of a term I think you'll be wasting a lot of time without ever getting close to the mission of Stack Overflow.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu wow! you're getting offensive but as I see from your comment you and probably OP too are not using correct markups for different elements. But developers should always write correct markup(for SEO) before adding CSS. And if I sense any time that someone is not paying attention to markups then I will tell them in order to help them.With respect :)

Comment: I don't really understand where I got offensive, so I'll stop before I do it again. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Using the `:visited` functionality is one option.  Another idea would be to, in the JavaScript function, add/remove a CSS class like `selected` which changes the font color. Just make sure that if you go the JavaScript/class route, you remove the `selected` class from the old item, as I've forgotten to do that many times

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Just use the .focus styling property .yearsx a:focus {